# Periodic Continued Fraction Formula for $\sqrt{a^2+4}$ for any non-zero integer $a$

Tags: continued-fractions

If $$x = \sqrt{ a^2 + 4 } $$ then I have conjectured that:

$$ x = [ a ; \overline{ \frac{a}{2} , 2a }] \ \ \ \text{ if a is even}$$

and $$ x = [ a ; \overline{ \frac{a}{2}, 1, 1, \frac{a}{2}, 2a } ]\ \ \  \text{            if a is odd} $$ where we take the floor of $\frac{a}{2} $

The even version is easy enough to prove. But for the odd version, we note that $$\frac{a}{2} = [\frac{a}{2}] + \frac{1}{2} = [\frac{a}{2}] + \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1}}$$
and I suspect that this is why the pair of ones emerges, but still a bit stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the usual development of a continued fraction.  It is important to express the first term as $\frac {a-1}2$ as that can be used in algebra instead of $\frac a2$ rounded down.
$$\frac 1{\sqrt{a^2+4}-a}=\frac {a-1}2+\frac {\sqrt{a^2+4}-a+2}4\\
\frac 4{\sqrt{a^2+4}-a+2}=1+\frac {\sqrt{a^2+4}-2}a\\
\frac a{\sqrt{a^2+4}-2}=1+\frac{\sqrt{a^2+4}+2-a}a\\\frac a{\sqrt{a^2+4}-(a-2)}=\frac{a-1}2+\frac {\sqrt{a^2+4}-a}4\\
\frac a{\sqrt{a^2+4}-a}=2a+(\sqrt{a^2+4}-a)$$
and you can read off the desired repeat.

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't done much stuff with the floor function, so I didn't really make the connection that I could simplify it so easily! Thanks again

Comment: Floor functions do not play nice with algebra, so you generally need to get rid of them.  Once you know that $a$ is odd, you can find that half rounded down is half the next lower number and get the expression that I used.